# Colorizing `functions/variables' within comments in `c-mode'

Tags: font-lock, c-mode

I am working with the C-source code of Emacs using the built-in `c-mode`, and would like Emacs to automatically highlight functions and variables within comments with a different color:  In the following example, how can I make `pos-visible-in-window-p` a different color?

```
/* See the doc-string for `pos-visible-in-window-p'.  */
```

Comment: Here's a start: `(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode '(("\`\\([a-z-]+\\)'" 1 'font-lock-function-name-face prepend)))`. This does not check if `\`foo'` is in a comment, though.

Comment: @Constantine -- my best *guess* would be that a modification of the function `c-font-lock-doc-comments` *might* be appropriate.  However, the method used by `c-mode` to achieve its highlighting is quite complex.

Comment: @lawlist are you looking for a way to find functions and variables? or, highlight anything within `' is ok? In the letter case, @Constantine 's answer is good enough, no?

Comment: @Yasushi Shoji -- I have grown accustomed to how the `emacs-lisp-mode` highlights functions and variables within comments, and find that I really miss that visual behavior when working in `c-mode`.  The answer of @Constantine is essentially a textbook example from `font-lock` class 101.  I'm most interested in a spiffy modification of the syntactic functions used by `c-mode` to achieve the desired effect.  I am already familiar with the find features for functions and variables.

Comment: @lawlist: Yes, the doc-comment machinery seems like the right place. (If we're lucky, adding one more style (in addition to `gtkdoc`, `autodoc`, and `javadoc`) would be enough -- it would be nice to leave the **logic** of `c-font-lock-doc-comments` alone). Also, I just realized that one could modify `bug-reference-mode` to achieve something similar. (That way we could easily have clickable buttons that call 'describe-function` or `describe-variable`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
(require 'cc-mode)

(setq yashi-font-lock-doc-comments
  (let ((symbol "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"))
    `((,(concat "`" symbol "'")
       0 ,c-doc-markup-face-name prepend nil))
    ))

(setq yashi-font-lock-keywords
  `((,(lambda (limit)
        (c-font-lock-doc-comments "/\\*" limit
          yashi-font-lock-doc-comments)
        ))))


(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq c-doc-comment-style '((c-mode . yashi)))))
```

Comment: The following test was performed with both Emacs 24.5 and also with the master branch:  I started with **Emacs -Q**.  I pasted the answer into the `*scratch*` buffer and typed `M-x eval-buffer RET`.  Then I opened a new buffer `foo.c`, which defaults to `c-mode`.  I typed:  `/* See the doc-string for [backtick]pos-visible-in-window-p'.  */`  The function `pos-visible-in-window-p` did not receive any different color than the rest of the comment -- i.e., the function is `font-lock-comment-face`.  I verified the face by placing my cursor on the function and typing:  `C-u C-x =`

Comment: @lawlist sorry about bugs.  First of all I've only tested with Emacs master branch. Second, I thought C can't have a symbol `foo-bar`,  so I committed `-` from symbol regexp.  Third, I left `/**\n` as the start of comment.  I've removed it too.  Would you mind to test it again?

Comment: When using this method, the comment will be highlighted using `font-lock-doc-face` instead of `font-lock-comment-face`. This indicates that this method was intended to be used for doxygen-like comments, not for general highlighting inside comments. One drawback is that you can only have one doc-style, so you can't highlight symbols and doxygen comments. An alternative approach would be to use a plain font-lock rule that highlight symbols inside backtick-tick, that also check that they are inside comments using `syntax-ppss`.